# Linq with complex join condition

Tags: linq

This is the script that is producing the firstname, lastname, and the email address of a group of contacts.

```
SELECT DISTINCT pvld.AllTeam, rc.FirstName, rc.LastName, rc.EmailAddress 
FROM CustomerPreferredVendorDetail pvld 
INNER JOIN Teams t ON t.TeamId = pvld.TeamId AND t.Active = 1 
INNER JOIN TeamMembers tm ON 
 (tm.TeamMemberId = pvld.TeamMemberId AND (pvld.AllTeam = 0 OR pvld.AllTeam IS NULL)) 
   OR 
 (tm.TeamId = t.TeamId AND pvld.AllTeam = 1) 
AND tm.Active = 1 
INNER JOIN ResourceContact rc ON rc.SupplierContactsID = tm.ResourceContactId  
           AND rc.Active = 1 
WHERE pvld.CustCompId = 4383
```

I'd like to write a linq query but I'm stuck with the condition of joining the **Teams** and **TeamMembers** tables. If the field AllTeam is false or null, then I need to join **TeamMembers** table using  TeamMemberId. Otherwise, I'll use **TeamId** to join.

This is how I've started writing the query:

```
var contactInfos = from pvld in _repository.GetQuery<CustomerPreferredVendorDetail>
                         (p => p.CustCompId == CustCompId)
                   join tm in _repository.GetAll<Team>()
                   on pvld.TeamId equals tm.TeamId
                   join tmbr in _repository.GetAll<TeamMember>()
                  on pvld.TeamMemberId equals () //.. this is where I'm stuck...
```

It looks like the join can only done with primitive values, not with a complex condition.

Is there a way to write the above SQL query into a linq one? Or do I need to make several calls to get the same result?

Comment: Are you doing this with Entity Framework?

Comment: Yes I'm using EF. I've wrote a version that hit the database 5 times. Now, I'd like to write one that hit the database only once.

Comment: Why not use a stored procedure, and add a strongly typed method to your repository using Database.SqlQuery?

Comment: have you tried this:
`on new { t1 = (pvld.AllTeam = 0 OR pvld.AllTeam IS NULL) ? tmbr.TeamMemberId : tm.TeamId } equals new { t1 = (pvld.AllTeam = 0 OR pvld.AllTeam IS NULL) ? pvld.TeamMemberId : tm.TeamId}`